# Python3.4 Anaconda: Input() Function Broken?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I'm having trouble with the input() function in Python3.4 using the Anaconda integrated editor.  If I just type

```
x = input()
```

into the editor, it returns a blank line that I can type text into.  If I type:

```
foo
```

into this line, I would expect 'foo' be stored as a string with variable name x.  But, instead I get:

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

To make the function work as expected, I must instead type in:

```
'foo'
```

which is unfortunate because what I *really* want is just to pause my code and wait for an arbitrary user input, and I read somewhere that "wait = input()" is the most pythonic way to do this.  Using that line in my actual script returns an "unexpected EOF" error - I assume as another symptom of the same problem.  Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Note: I suspect this is an Anaconda-specific problem, given the following reference:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3?  That `NameError` is exactly the error you'd expect to see if you did this in Python 2 (where the solution is to use `raw_input` instead of `input`).  As a test, what happens if you try using `raw_input` here?

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Different versions between my home computer and the server.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is being run by Python 2, not 3.  I don't know enough about Anaconda to know if the problem is with their editor, or if you have your path messed up, but the problem is that the wrong version of Python is being used.